# Hololens Spatial mapping issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

While using Spatial mapping, I get an error at:

```
void Update()
{
    if (mappingEnabled)
    {
        foreach (GameObject surface in surfaces.Values)
        {
            surface.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = DrawVisualMeshes;
        }

        if (surfaceWorkOutstanding == false && surfaceDataQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            SurfaceData smsd = surfaceDataQueue.Dequeue();
            surfaceWorkOutstanding = Observer.RequestMeshAsync(smsd, Observer_OnDataReady);
        }
    }
}
```

The last line gets an ArgumentNullException. The code is part of the hololens tutorials so nothing in there is mine.

The crash happens even if I am not doing any action, just gazing around.

The null argument is within the smsd struct;

```
-       $exception  {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: dataRequest.outputMesh"} System.ArgumentNullException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `surfaces.Values` List or array?

Comment: None, surfaces is a dictionary and Values returns a ValueCollection object so most likely just a ICollection. Still, the issue does not come from this object. The SurfaceData is a struct that contains MeshFilter, WorldAnchor and MeshCollider. It is filled when the Observer gets updated but for some reason it is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [MS site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/spatial_mapping_in_unity):

> Render the spatial surface with the latest mesh and (optionally) use
>   it for physics collisions and raycasts. It's important to confirm that
>   the contents of the `SurfaceData` are not null.

This simply means that you have to check if `smsd`  is `null` before calling and passing it into `Observer.RequestMeshAsync` function.

```
if (mappingEnabled)
    {
        foreach (GameObject surface in surfaces.Values)
        {
            surface.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = DrawVisualMeshes;
        }

        if (surfaceWorkOutstanding == false && surfaceDataQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            SurfaceData smsd = surfaceDataQueue.Dequeue();
            if (smsd.outputMesh == null || smsd.outputCollider == null || smsd.outputAnchor == null) { return; }
            {
                surfaceWorkOutstanding = Observer.RequestMeshAsync(smsd, Observer_OnDataReady);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: smsd is a struct so it cannot be null. The null object is the mesh reference within the struct. Seems it is a bad design of the script as they totally changed it to a new implementation. Think i read it has a memory leak.

Comment: I did not know that `SurfaceData` is a struct. Still, if you look inside of it, you will likely find the mesh data. You should check if that is `null` like Microsoft said on their site before passing it in `RequestMeshAsync` function. I believe this should solve the problem.

Comment: yes this is what I did and seems to work for now. There is a thread somewhere I read that was stating that the current code on hololens tutorial website (one I am using) is kinda non-working and has been update, so this sounds like a temp hack. But will do for quick demo. Thanks. I will update your answer when I find the link.

Comment: Hololens is still new and the API is about 6 months old so I expect you to run into more problems. That's normal. Just file a bug with Microsoft when you encounter problems like these. You may want to go [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/HolographicAcademy/tree/Holograms-230-SpatialMapping) for the latest sample code. I saw something about Bug fixes in the comment section.